# How to make the main menu expanded?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have set main menu items expanded but when I print them in page.tpl.php($main_menu) there are no children for menu items.How can I make them expanded?

Comment: If this is a theming question, you should state the name of the theme you are currently using, and perhaps if dropdowns are a big deal for your theme to select one that uses dropdowns to begin with - e.g. http://drupal.org/project/acquia_marina

Comment: @wiifm: It's my own theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the theme you're using. Unfortunatelly, some of them -- including the Dupal's default Bartik -- don't display children in the main menu.

You can either install a theme that does display menu children, or -- if you are using Bartik -- you can make use of the [Drop-down menus subtheme for Bartik](http://deltup.org/download.php?view.6) or follow the [HOWTO create dropdown menus for Bartik in Drupal 7](http://deltup.org/page.php?4/bartik).

Answer (score 4):

Go to `admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu` and edit the parents that have children that you wish to show, and click the tickbox 'show expanded'

Or alternatively install the module http://drupal.org/project/menu_expanded which brings back the tickbox on the menu 'list items' page ala drupal 6

Hope this helps

Comment: In the question NKmhr says he has "set main menu items expanded". I'm afraid the problem is rather the theme, which won't show menu children even when parents are set to expanded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading your menu via page.tpl and it doesn`t have children viewed - you can add it via block and it will have ones.