# Fast way to make all menu-links "Show as expanded"?

Tags: routes

Is there a way to automatically make all menu-links in all menus whatsoever "Show as expanded"?

I have about 4 menus that contain many links and it's not serious to pass one by one and click "show as expanded".

Is there a module or a script that will do that automatically? Thanks,

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/how-to-make-the-main-menu-expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) and create block what level you want to trail you menu. You can also use [menu expanded](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_expanded) as per your requirement. Menu expanded is not well maintained.